# Django Model seeking alternative to many to many fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am writing an exam system, below is my model:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )

class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    topic = models.ForeignKey(
        Topic
    )

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    choice_text = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
    )
    is_right_answer = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
```

I want when I create an exam, i can give multiple topics like `math`, `physics`, `business` etc and then i can query all the questions related that topics and show in the frontend.

My problem only in exam creation, i am not getting should I use ManyToManyField or there is any alternative solution

I just want to select multiple `topic` during i create an exam. Can anyone help me in this  case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)** is the way to go here.

This can be achieved in one of two ways:

**Adding `ManyToManyField` in one of the two models**

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)
```

**Using a `through` model**

```
class ExamTopic(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, through=ExamTopic)
```

The advantage of a `through` model is if you want to add additional information to the relationship, let's say a field for examiner

e.g.

```
class ExamTopic(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    examinar = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM's `ManyToManyField` corresponds to `many to many` relationship of a relational database. I suppose, you want an exam to have multiple topics and a topic can be tagged to multiple exams. This is a classic `many to many` relationship scenario. You should go with `ManyToManyField()`